# How to display result set only if there is value from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

```
DECLARE @ONYX_ID INT

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT iIndividualID 
    FROM [ONYX_KAPLAN].[dbo].[Individual]
    WHERE iIndividualID  <= 1010918

OPEN Cur

FETCH NEXT From cur INTO @ONYX_ID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    ----How to say not to create result set if no value-----------
    ---Unable to create temp table in this database-------
    EXEC csprgCustomerProduct_TranscriptItem_KAP  @ONYX_ID

    FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @ONYX_ID
END

CLOSE Cur
DEALLOCATE Cur
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by `no value`. This sounds like something that should be excluded in the query used for the cursor, but its not clear. Also not clear why you would need to create a temp table.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you don't want result-set if `csprgCustomerProduct_TranscriptItem_KAP` doesn't return any record.

So, you can use IF EXISTS in your result-set of procedure. If exists any record in your return query than and then it should give result else no result-set.